# How wide would the current be?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetohydrodynamics

I recently saw the sketch of the magnetohydrodynamic drive of the [YAMATO 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamato_1) and it occurs to me that one of my teacher has told me the current would, even when traveling in a plane, stay in a line and not spreading throughout the plane. I am wondering how would the electricity flow through the two electrodes, would they spread throughout the volume of seawater (meaning there are charges flowing everywhere inside the water in the pipe) running through the pipe or only go from one point on the anode to another point on the cathode(one straight line)? [image: The front and side view of the MHD]

Comment: Currents respond to electric and magnetic fields (i.e., forces) just like most other things in the universe.  So what forces would drive the currents away from a "straight line"?  What forces are acting to keep the current going in a "straight line"?